# Proof of a Combinatorial Summation

Tags: summation, combinations

- How many bitstrings of length $n+1$ have exactly $k+1$ many $1$s?
- Let $i$ be an integer with $k\leq i\leq n$. What is the number of bitstrings of length $n+1$ that have exactly $k+1$ many $1$s and in which the rightmost $1$ is at position $i+1$?
- Use the above two results to prove that
  $$
  \sum_{i=k}^n \binom{i}{k} = \binom{n+1}{k+1}.
  $$

I have the first 2 bullets figured out however I'm not sure how to go about proving the summation using what I have for the first 2 bullets?

Any help would be great :)

Comment: When there are $k+1$ $1$'s, the rightmost one has a position among $\{k+1, k+2,\ldots, n\}$.

Comment: this question has been asked a ton of times before.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, your answer to the first bullet point is $\binom{n+1}{k+1}$, and the second bullet point is $\binom{i}{k}$.

If a bitstring has $k+1$ 1s occurring in it, it must have a rightmost 1.  So, by summing $\binom{i}{k}$ over $i$ (i.e., over all rightmost 1 positions), we have found another way of counting all bitstrings of length $n+1$ with $k+1$ 1s.  (The terminals on the summation may be shortened since $\binom{i}{k}=0$ when $i<k$.)

This is the method of [double counting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_counting_(proof_technique)).